How to export clean HTML code in text variable from R to pdf, html, and xlsx
I'm having trouble with a R data frame where I pulled data from XBRL. One variable named "fact" contains HTML code. As you can see in the following table:
| endDate  | fact |
| -------- | -------- |
|2022-12-31| `<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'></span> 
 <p style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:.05pt;margin-bottom:0cm; margin-left:0cm;text-autospace:none"><span style='font-family:"Times New Roman",serif; '>&#160;</span></p> <div align='left'><table class='usertable'>
<thead> <tr class='row'> <td width="182" valign="top" style="width:136.15pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm"> <div align="center" style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:1.4pt; margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;text-align:center;text-autospace:none">Saldo al 31/12/2022</div> </td> <td width="182" valign="top" style="width:136.15pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm"> <div align="center" style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:1.4pt; margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;text-align:center;text-autospace:none">Saldo al 31/12/2021</div> </td> <td width="161" valign="top" style="width:120.6pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm"> <div align="center" style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:1.4pt; margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;text-align:center;text-autospace:none">Variazioni</div> </td> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr class='row'> <td width="182" valign="top" style="width:136.15pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm"> <div align="right" style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:1.4pt; margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;text-align:right;text-autospace:none">10.256.176</div> </td> <td width="182" valign="top" style="width:136.15pt;border-top:none;border-left: none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm"> <div align="right" style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:1.4pt; margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;text-align:right;text-autospace:none">6.106.438 </div> </td> <td width="161" valign="top" style="width:120.6pt;border-top:none;border-left: none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm"> <div align="right" style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:1.4pt; margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;text-align:right;text-autospace:none">4.149.738</div> </td> </tr> </tbody></table> </div> <p style="margin-bottom:0cm"><span style='font-family:"Times New Roman",serif; '>&#160;</span></p> <p style="margin-bottom:0cm"><span style='font-family:"Times New Roman",serif; '>&#160;</span></p> <p style="margin-bottom:0cm"><span style='font-family:"Times New Roman",serif'>&#160;</span></p>`|

Code represent a 2X3 table
I tried to export in pdf, xlsx and html
write_xlsx(
df,
path =  '//UN/PA/UND/UND_C/xbrl/test.xlsx',
col_names = TRUE,
format_headers = TRUE,
use_zip64 = FALSE)

library(gridExtra)
pdf('//UN/PA/UND/UND_C/xbrl/test.pdf", height=11, width=10)
grid.table(df)
dev.off()

and so on...
I expect to have the following result



endDate
fact




2022-12-31
Balance at 31/12/2022
Variations



10,256,176
4,149,738



The result, however, it is always similar to the image attached.
html code trouble
